# Ensure float appears directly after `\afterpage` and `landscape`

Tags: floats, page-breaking, landscape

I have a large (full page) landscape figure that I would like to appear on the page opposite to a large (full page) portrait figure. The landscape figure is generated like so:

```
\afterpage{
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{path/to/the/file.pdf}
            \caption{The Caption}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
}
```

The `afterpage` allows the landscape page to float around. I would now like to add a figure that is on the opposite page; I have done so currently by adding it into the `landscape` and rotating it:

```
\afterpage{
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{path/to/the/file.pdf}
            \caption{The Caption}
        \end{figure}

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1,angle=-90]{path/to/another/file.pdf}
            \caption{The Other Caption}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
}
```

This has a couple of problems with it, though - firstly, it doesn't ensure that they're on facing pages (only that they're on consecutive pages), and secondly it results in a rotated caption for the second figure, which is not ideal because it's really a portrait figure.

I have looked for a solution to this problem, but can't seem to find it. Can anyone suggest one, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @wakjah `\cleardoublepage` and the `twoside` option (if you're using the `article` class) are probably your friend. But you'll probably get a more comprehensive answer from someone that actually knows Latex if you include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/14210).

Answer (score 4):

I'd just put the second figure after landscape rather than rotating it twice.

```
\afterpage{%
\clearpage
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{path/to/the/file.pdf}
            \caption{The Caption}
        \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics{path/to/another/file.pdf}
            \caption{The Other Caption}
        \end{figure}
\clearpage
}
```

To check that it starts on an even page you should be able to do

```
\afterpage{\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}
\afterpage{...}
\else
...
\fi
}
```

so it gets deferred again if it lands on an odd page.